# Jekyll install error on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ubuntu-11.10, jekyll

I am trying to create a blog using [jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll). I am using Ubuntu 11.10, but after I installed the ruby gem and try to run it locally on my server i get the following error:
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:926:in `report_activate_error': Could not find

```
RubyGem jekyll (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:244:in `activate_dep'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:236:in `activate'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1307:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:18
```

I think it is a problem with mu ruby gems path.
My gem env output is as follows:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-02-16 patchlevel 125) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/swaroop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@test
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/swaroop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/swaroop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@test/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/swaroop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@test
     - /home/swaroop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

How do I rectify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was to prefix it with sudo
i.e.,

```
sudo jekyll --server
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good approach to call it with `sudo`. That it's working with `sudo` seems like you have not installed the gem under user you are without `sudo`.

I recommend you

1. look at https://github.com/plusjade/jekyll-bootstrap.git. It help you with few things.
2. Start use Bundler ( https://github.com/roolo/roolo.github.com/blob/master/Gemfile ). It will help you to have same version as on Github for future deployment in there.

   - try to clone my blog and then run bundle in dir of the repo